# Starbursts on dodecahedron surface

Tags: three.js

I am pretty new to three js and I am trying to create some stars on Dodecahedron Surface. However, I got an errors on getRandomPointOnDodecahedron. Any help on how to create that function. Working file: https://github.com/Triple1331/Question/blob/main/Question/starsOn.js

Comment: To get a useful answer, it might be a good idea to: Post the errors you are getting. explain what you mean by "starbursts", maybe with an image.

Comment: Ideally, share [`a Minimal, Reproducible Example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).